# fdisk -l | grep command with wildcard doesn't show results

Tags: grep, wildcards, fdisk

Why commands

```
fdisk -l | grep sd? 
fdisk -l | grep sd??
```

don't work in this situation and

```
fdisk -l | grep sd[ab]
```

works ?

[image: terminal window]

Comment: First of all you should quote these arguments with `?` or `*` or `[…]` or any syntax that can trigger shell globbing if you don't wan't shell globbing to occur. If your current directory contained `sdb` and/or `sda`, the output of `fdisk -l | grep sd[ab]` would be different. Any answer you get that intents to pass `?` or `*` to `grep` and doesn't put it in quotes is flawed.

Comment: Nakini thank you for editing my question :] 

Kamil thank you for the lesson about quotes. Dziekuje bardzo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all regular expressions in `grep` are same as `shell`. For listing the disk with *?*, use the following

```
fdisk -l | grep 'sd?*'
```

In fact, the above could be achieved with the following simplified version:

```
fdisk -l | grep sd
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer Nakini. It worked perfectly.

Kamil I created files with touch like you suggested but                            

fdisk -l | grep 'sd?*'

returned only devices and not any of those files.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski, I do agree with your both of the concerns. I updated my answer with your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You probably meant to use `egrep`:

```
fdisk -l | grep sd..?
```

But it could be enough to employ the right regular expression:

```
fdisk -l | grep 'sd.\|sd..'
```

**Explanation:**

`egrep` is equivalent to `grep -E`, employing a different, enhanced, version of [regular expressions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/).

`.` means *any character*

`\|` means *or*

See man grep:

> ```
> -E, --extended-regexp
>        Interpret PATTERN as an extended regular  expression  (ERE,  see below).
>
>    grep understands three different versions of regular expression syntax:
>    “basic”  (BRE), “extended” (ERE) and “perl” (PCRE).  In GNU grep, there
>    is no difference in available functionality between basic and  extended
>    syntaxes.  In other implementations, basic regular expressions are less
>    powerful.   The  following  description  applies  to  extended  regular
>    expressions;  differences  for basic regular expressions are summarized
>    afterwards.   Perl-compatible  regular  expressions   give   additional
>    functionality,  and are documented in pcresyntax(3) and pcrepattern(3),
>    but work only if PCRE is available in the system.
>
>    The period . matches any single character.
>
> Alternation
>    Two regular expressions may be joined by the infix operator |; the resulting regular expression matches any string matching either alternate expression.
> ```

Comment: Two issues: (1) Your first example doesn't use `egrep`. :) (2) It will do something else after `touch sd..1 sd..2`. I hope you know why.